# Re-Partition Tool for Large Drives

Tags: partition

Say you have a server with a 25GB C partition, and a 450GB D partition - the C drive is running out of space.

I've used some products that offer repartitioning but "up to" 300GB drives. Any good repartition tools out there that can handle large drives at a reasonable price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had great success with [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/) products, which support both Windows and Linux filesystems.  It's a commercial company, so its products aren't free.  But I have been happy with their tools.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)?  I'd don't know if has any limits but I've always used it successfully in the past for partitions in the 200 GB range.

Comment: Note that it will potentially take *forever* if there is data in the partitions and you are going to move them (e.g. to make room for the partition in front of them to grow). Move empty partitions only, if possible.

Comment: That is very true.

Comment: And think of defragmenting thoroughly before trying to resize a partition.

Answer (score 0):

[GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) should do what you need.  It's an open source non-destructive repartitioning tool that's included in virtually every linux LiveCD, and it understands and deals with windows partitions just fine.  It has a partition size limit of 2TB, according to [this](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=1125).  This may have changed to be larger since that discussion, but it should handle partitions of at least up to 2TB.

You can find a decent tutorial here:

http://blogcritics.org/scitech/article/non-destructive-partitioning-with-gparted/

You can see in it's feature matrix that it'll grow, shrink, and move FAT16, FAT32, and NTFS, which should meet your needs perfectly.

Note that Windows Vista doesn't like repartiioning operations - you'll need your installation disk and to follow a few simple steps in this tutorial to repair it after the resize:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

You probably already fixed your problem but to add to the information repo, you can use gparted from a Rescue Is Possible bootable disc...

Also, while it's non-destructive, there's always the possibility that you could lose data in the process. *backup backup backup* if at all possible first. The investment in a (relatively) small external hard disk to create an image of your disk to first could be a real benefit, with the bonus of having a good external hard disk to use for data storage after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Extend system partition to maximize computer performance as well as better manage hard disk usage. By the way, you may find that there is not enough free space on a certain partition and want to solve this low disk problem.here is a detail : http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/help/resizing-and-moving-partition.htm